# Adding Many to Many relationships properly to routes in flask sql-alchemy

Tags: flask

I have created some models to represent a Many to Many relationship, which looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

class Token(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tokens'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('top_coins_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    ...
    locations = relationship("Location", secondary="token_locations")

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            ...
            'locations': self.locations
        }
    
class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('locations_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    ...
    tokens = relationship("Token", secondary="token_locations")

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.location_name,
            'symbol': self.location_description,
        }
    
class Token_Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'token_locations'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('token_locations_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    token_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tokens.id'))
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('locations.id'))
    token = relationship(Token, backref=backref("token_locations", cascade="all, delete-orphan"),overlaps="locations,tokens")
    location = relationship(Location, backref=backref("token_locations", cascade="all, delete-orphan"),overlaps="locations,tokens")

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'token_id': self.token_id,
            'token': self.token,
            'location_id': self.location_id,
            'location': self.location
        }
```

It seems to work fine, but I have no idea how update the records in the routes.py file of my application. Here's what I have tried:

```
@app.route('/update_token/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def update_token(id):
    if not request.form:
        abort(400)
    token = Token.query.get(id)
    if token is None:
        abort(404)
    token.name = request.form.get('name', token.name)
    ...
    token.website = request.form.get('website', token.website)

    token_location = Token_Location.query.all()
    token_location.token_id = request.form.get('token', token_location.token_id)
    token_location.location_id = request.form.get('location', token_location.location_id)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

I have tried this a few different ways. I would like to see a tutorial that doesn't just explain the models, but then also shows you how the routes can properly handle them. Please feel free to share any links you have.